# Can I use Fabric to workon a virtualenv and run a Python application?

Tags: python, fabric

I have `virtualenvwrapper` and `virtualenv` installed on an Ubuntu 11.10 machine. I currently use a shell script to `workon` a virtualenv, and then run a Python application. Something like this:

```
workon $1
export PYTHONPATH=/media/work/application-$2/src
cd $PYTHONPATH/core
python startapp.py -option1 $3 -option2 $4 --loglevel=INFO
```

I'd like to switch to Fabric rather than bash (with an eventual goal of making this invocation cross-platform). Can I use Fabric, which is itself a Python application, to make these kinds of calls on the local system? (`workon`, `export`, `python`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you can even look at [the section in the FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/faq.html#my-cd-workon-export-etc-calls-don-t-seem-to-work) related to this very question.

-- Update --

With newer versions of Fabric you can now use the prefix() context manager see [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/context_managers.html?highlight=workon)

Comment: I totally missed that, and it's very helpful for my use case, thanks!

Comment: n/p that's exactly why I lurk. When I'm to busy to write more patches, might as well get people using the old ones haha.

Comment: `local` calls won't catch `workon` if it's just a shell alias defined in .bashrc . It either needs to be in the path, or you need prepend something that calls .bashrc in your command chain like `source ~/.bashrc && ...` or `/bin/bash -l -c "..."`